# Issue with Javascript accepting user data for canvas pie chart

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to generate a simple pie chart using canvas, but its not displaying anything when data is assigned to an array used to draw the chart. I cant seem to find out exactly what the issue is.

Ive tried to convert the array to integers using a loop but it still won't use the data to draw the graph.

```js
function draw() {
var n = document.getElementById("data").value;
var values = n.split(",");
//document.write(values);
var colors = [ "blue", "red", "yellow", "green", "black" ];
var canvas = document.getElementById( "myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext( "2d" );  

  // grey background
context.fillStyle = "rgb(200,200,200)";
context.fillRect (0, 0, 600, 450);
                       
//iterate through array and assign values to integers
for( var i = 0; i < values.length; i++ ){    
    values[i] = parseInt(values[i]);
}
// get length of data array 
var dataLength = values.length; 
// variable to store all values
var total = 0;  


// calculate total 
for( var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++ ){    
    // add data value to total     
    total += values[ i ]; 
}  

// declare X and Y coordinates
var x = 100; 
var y = 100; 
var radius = 100; 

// declare starting point
var startingPoint = 0; 

for( var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++ ){     
        // calculate percent of total for current value     
        var percent = values[ i ][ 1 ] * 100 / total;      
        // calculate end point using the percentage (2 is the final point for the chart)     
        var endPoint = startingPoint + ( 2 / 100 * percent );
        // draw chart segment for current element     
        context.beginPath();        
        // select corresponding color     
        context.fillStyle = colors[ i ];     
        context.moveTo( x, y );     
        context.arc( x, y, radius, startingPoint * Math.PI, endPoint * Math.PI );         
        context.fill();      
        // starting point for next element     
        startingPoint = endPoint; 
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Easy Graph</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <style type = "text/css">
            canvas {
                    border: 2px solid black;
            }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="pie.js"> 

        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <h2> Pie chart </h2>
        <h2> Enter values seperated by commas</h2>
            <input type="text" name="number" id="data"><br>
            <input type="button" value="submit" name="submit" onclick = "draw();">
            <input type="button" value="Clear" name="Clear" onclick="reset()"><br><br>
        <canvas id ="myCanvas" width= "600" height= "300">
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This like is wrong:

```
var percent = values[ i ][ 1 ] * 100 / total;
```

It should be this way

```
var percent = values[ i ] * 100 / total;
```

You're trying to get a position in the array that doesn't exist.